# Change specific elements of a matrix puzzle - Python

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I have to solve how to replace the elements below zero elements with zeros and output the sum of the remaining elements in the matrix.

For example, [[0,3,5],[3,4,0],[1,2,3]] should output the sum of 3 + 5 + 4 + 1 + 2, which is 15.

So far:

```
def matrixElementsSum(matrix):
    out = 0
    # locate the zeros' positions in array & replace element below
    for i,j in enumerate(matrix):
        for k,l in enumerate(j):
                if l == 0:
                break
            out += l 
    return out
```

The code outputs seemingly random numbers. 
Can someone fix what's wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily drop elements that are below a zero element is by using [the zip function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
def matrixElementsSum(matrix):
    out = 0
    # locate the zeros' positions in array & replace element below
    for i,j in enumerate(matrix):
        # elements in the first row cannot be below a '0'
        if i == 0:
            out += sum(j)
        else:
            k = matrix[i-1]
            for x, y in zip(j, k):
                if y != 0:
                     out += x
    return out
```

Now consider naming your variables a little more meaningfully. Something like:

```
def matrixElementsSum(matrix):
    out = 0
    # locate the zeros' positions in array & replace element below
    for row_number, row in enumerate(matrix):
        # elements in the first row cannot be below a '0'
        if row_number == 0:
            out += sum(row)
        else:
            row_above = matrix[row_number - 1]
            for element, element_above in zip(row, row_above):
                if element_above != 0:
                     out += element
    return out
```

You should look into [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to make the code even more readable.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I asked for, and thanks for the pointers. Additionally, how would you do it to block out all of the rows below?